# Is there any way to capture Android's back button in mobile webkit browsers?

Tags: android, mobile, webkit

I know that in PhoneGap there's a way to do this, but can it be done for an HTML5 web app? I'd like to have Android users be able to use the back button within the webapp to provide a consistent UX, but of course the default is to go back in the browser history and leave the app...

Edit: tried, didn't do anything on any button press on a Google Nexus S:

```
document.onkeydown = checkKeycode;
function checkKeycode(e) {
    var keycode;
    if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
    else if (e) keycode = e.which;
    alert("keycode: " + keycode);
}
```

Edit again: The ultimate answer seems to be to create history points at each UX interaction -- using URL hashes like #!/main/about_us in the URL. This then allows for back-button use, so long as you make sure that the UI triggers a history.back() when a UI back button is tapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ultimate answer seems to be to create history points at each UX interaction -- using URL hashes like #!/main/about_us in the URL. This then allows for back-button use, so long as you make sure that the UI triggers a history.back() when a UI back button is tapped.

Answer (score -1):

Override the OnKeyDown Event in your app and look for KEYCODE_BACK.

If you are handling the event then return true else false.

Comment: I gave this a try, but none of the Android buttons return a keycode.